# using tasklist to list applications alone

Tags: windows, tasklist

how do you use tasklist command in windows to list only the currently opened applications?(not processes).In taskmanager the applications tab lists only the applications .Is this possible using the above command?

Comment: do you want it returned to your application through a command line argument or you just want to open the window and see it?

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhat that it just enumerates the top-level windows and considers their owner processes to be "applications".

Comment: I want the list to be available to my app.I don't want to open any window .just running tasklist command causes all processes to be listed.but I need only the list of applications(as shown in taskmanager applications tab)

Answer (score 0):

Tasklist gives you list of all those process which are currently running same as task manager.
But mostly it shows currently runnig apps at the end. for this yu can try "tasklist /svc" apps running you are supposed to use TaskManager.[Command prompt](http://new-tech-life.com/how-to-end-processes-using-using-command-prompt-cmd/)